# How to select item in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to select item in ListBox in program, but I was so far unable to do so.

I looked for the answer but everything I found was to use `ListBox.SetSelected()` method, but I don't have anything like that awaiable.

I discovered that there are two completely different ListBoxes and I am using the second one:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
System.Windows.Controls.ListBox
```

All items in the ListBox are added via Binding, which doesn't help either. Any ideas?

**EDIT :**

I just found that this works:

```
listBox.SelectedIndex = 5;
listBox.UpdateLayout();
listBox.Focus();
```

Apparently, I was missing the last method, which sets the highlight to the selected item, which was updating fine even before.

Comment: can you please show some more code including what you have tried in order to set the selected item in the listbox?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried SelectedItem.

example:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox.
   string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting it via the `SelectedIndex` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx or the `SelectedItem` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx or `SelectedItems` (for multiple selection) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: Sure, I've tried all three. They will select item, but they won't highlight it. You apparently need `.UpdateLayout()` and most importantly `.Focus()` after that...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation from the MSDN site on setting the selected item in a listbox. Here it is being done on a button click event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("One");
    listBox1.Items.Add("Two");
    listBox1.Items.Add("Three");
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.FindString("Two");
}
```

Comment: Well thanx, but this one is from `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` which I am not using. There is no `FindString()`...

Answer (score 0):

To get the currently selected item use

```
ListBox.SelectedItems()
```